# App_Code class not auto completing and cant use it in rest of project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a site and thought I would do it correctly so I created an `App_Code` directory and created a class in there.

when im editing the class file the auto complete no longer works, which I can live with, however, no matter what I do in my main site I cant access or reference the class file.

ive tried 
putting a using statement at the top of the file, but it just throws an error
creating an instance of the class in the code but that throws and error

can someone let me know where im going wrong

thanks

Comment: Please post a snippet of your class so that we can detect if there are any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`App_Code` is used for `Website projects` and not for `Web Application projects`. It will not work as expected for web application projects. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23.aspx)

Is your project a website or web application?

Comment: Presuming from what you have said I think it must be a website project. I have just deleted the App_Code dir and just created a class file in my project which now works.

Comment: Good. I think you mean `it must be a web application project`. If it is a web site project it should work. :)

Comment: yes thanks your right, ive just checked in visual studio and the top project in the list if creating a new one is we application project. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your class is `public`

**EDIT:** And as [@Oded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530834/app-code-class-not-auto-completing-and-cant-use-it-in-rest-of-project/10530880#comment13621976_10530880) has commented, remove the `Namespace`

Comment: Just checked and its like this :
namespace MyNameSpce
{
    public class SiteMenus
    {

Comment: @andrewslaughter - Drop the namespace

Comment: got rid of the namespace line, however I still cant reference it from my other file code file if I do this SiteMenus tt = new SiteMenus(); I get the error: type or namespace Sitemenus could not be found...